# What's wrong with this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

```
var allHTMLElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < allHTMLElements.length; i++) {
    if (allHTMLElements[i].getAttribute("group") && allHTMLElements[i].getAttribute("index")) continue;
    allHTMLElements[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

---

```
<div group="myGroup">Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
<div index="d534">Hello</div>
```

All the divs turn red and the ones with group and index do not stay the default color. Only the middle should turn red but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're using an `&&` when you should be using `||`

```
if (allHTMLElements[i].getAttribute("group") || allHTMLElements[i].getAttribute("index")) continue;
```

Comment: Why is it that this answer, even though it is just as good as the top voted one, and better than the second one, have so much fewer upvotes?

Answer (score 6):

You want to use "or" instead of "and":

```
allHTMLElements[i].getAttribute("group") || allHTMLElements[i].getAttribute("index")
```

Answer (score 2):

your if statement should be ORing them, not ANDing them